# IONIC 3: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-maps, typescript, geolocation, ionic3

I am studying IONIC 3, and now I am developing an app usig Google Maps API. The issue is that I am trying to execute my app, but when it's launched, there is appearing this message:

**inicio.html**

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 
'nativeElement' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined
```

This is the piece of code which is generating the problem:

**inicio.ts (Just a part of the code)**

```
loadMap(){

this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position)=>{

  let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                      position.coords.longitude);

  let mapOptions = {
    center: latLng,
    zoom: 15,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }

  this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, 
  mapOptions);

  }, (err) => {
  console.log(err);
  });

}
```

**inicio.ts (Full code)**

```
import { Component,ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

declare var google: any;

/**
* Generated class for the InicioPage page.
*
* See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more 
info on
* Ionic pages and navigation.
*/

@IonicPage()
@Component({
selector: 'page-inicio',
templateUrl: 'inicio.html',
})
export class InicioPage {

@ViewChild('map') mapElement: ElementRef;
map: any; //Google map manager.
coords : any = { lat:0, lng: 0 } 

constructor(
public navCtrl: NavController, 
public navParams: NavParams,
public platform: Platform,
public geolocation: Geolocation) {

  platform.ready().then(() => {
      //Platform ready. All plugins enabled.
  });
}

ionViewDidLoad() {
console.log('ionViewDidLoad InicioPage');
this.loadMap();
}

loadMap(){

this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position)=>{

  let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                      position.coords.longitude);

  let mapOptions = {
    center: latLng,
    zoom: 15,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }

this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, 
mapOptions);

}, (err) => {
  console.log(err);
});

}
}
```

**inicio.html**

```
<!--
Generated template for the InicioPage page.

See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more 
info on
Ionic pages and navigation.
-->
<ion-header>

<ion-navbar>
<ion-title>Inicio</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>
<!--<h1> Esta es la página de inicio, aquí situaremos un mapa con un 
boton de añadir lugar.</h1>-->
<div id="map"></div>

</ion-content>
```

**inicio.scss**

```
page-inicio {

ion-content{
    .scroll{
        height: 100%;   
    }
    #map{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
}

}
```

Thanks for your help!.

Comment: Sounds like a DI error, can you please add the class constructor to your question? Also, please add the declaration and initialization for the `mapElement` property.

Comment: Done!. Full code added.

Comment: I thnk you need to move the code into something like `ngAfterViewInit` as the `@ViewChild('map')` may not yet be available in the `ionViewDidLoad` lifecycle hook. I don't remember which hook to use 
though.

Comment: I put inside of ngAfterViewInit the call to loadMap(). Still not working. :(

Comment: and your template contains a tag like `<div #map>`?

Comment: Yes. <div id="map"></div>.

Comment: There's a lot wrong with your code, e.g. `coords : any = { lat:0, lng: 0 }` (the `: any` is extra code that reduces the quality of your types) is some of the worst TypeScript you could possibly write, but I can't see what's leading to the specific issue sorry.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. ;)

Comment: You could also receive this error if you have the map in a section (aka hidden on load) - ensure your functions execute when the section is visible to avoid

Answer (score 6):

In your HTML you need to change

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

to

```
<div #map id="map"></div>
```

Then `@ViewChild('map') mapElement: ElementRef;` will resolve correctly.

See [this](https://www.joshmorony.com/the-difference-between-viewchildren-and-contentchildren/) for more details.

Comment: Please amend your answer and add a few words about the context of your solution and brief description of the off-site resources that you point to. Please also see [answer].

Comment: LMAO, same thing just happened to me. I removed the `#map` from the HTML then I started wondering why I was getting this error. @Daniel, were you following a Josh Morony tutorial? https://www.joshmorony.com/ionic-2-how-to-use-google-maps-geolocation-video-tutorial/

Comment: It's from Angular's core if anyone's new on the elementRef resolve: `import { ElementRef } from '@angular/core';`

Answer (score 1):

This is late, but for those who still have the error after following the tutorial by Josh from [here](https://www.joshmorony.com/ionic-2-how-to-use-google-maps-geolocation-video-tutorial/). I solved my error just by placing the **loadMap()** function call in **ionViewDidLoad()** instead of in the **constructor()**